# http request on file input using post

Tags: html, forms, http, httprequest

What, precisely is submitted to the webserver in a file upload http request?

ie. If I have the following form,

```
<form action=%URL% method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input name="fileinfo" type="file" /><br />
     <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

What is the request that will be sent to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will be something like below... just use print_r to see what is going into your script

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);

 [fileinfo] => Array
    (
        [name] => MyFile.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
        [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
        [size] => 98174
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know how to print the requests without using php by the way? It seems a shame to have to install it just for this, everything else server-side is written in python.

Comment: I assumed PHP since you didn't specify any language and python wasn't in your tags for question.  I'm sure for python it will be very different.  maybe somebody else can reply with python method. sry